Github actions cant login to AZURE
[CAN SOMEONE please help me with this
I think it is a secret problem and
this is the command I am using for the secrets
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "app-test-1" --role contributor \
                        --scopes /subscriptions/your_subscription_id/resourceGroups/your_resource_group \
                        --sdk-auth



I was expecting to deploy CI/CD through GitHub actions.

Try without slash at the beginning here subscriptions/your_subscription_id/resourceGroups/your_resource_group

Where you are running the script? In yaml file or in CodeSpace in GitHub.

in azure cloudshell and then saving the output in git secrets

it ain't working tried that combo before

You need to follow the steps to assign role using az ad sp create-for-rbac from GitHub codespace:

as the error says --sdk-auth is deprecated. you cannot use --sdk-authnow.
you need to login to your azure account first. using az login --use-device-code, as interactive login does not work in codespace.


Note :- because ports are blocked in codesapce.

This is the command which worked for me.
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "myApp" --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/devflask



Make sure your subscription id is valid
make sure you have required role/permission to assign roles in your subscription
Make sure that the resource provider you are trying to assign role, it exists and is accessible at the tenant level. Some Azure services and features require tenant-level permissions.


OUPUT:



